# Is there a way to to fire some code before user validation?

Tags: users, validation

Am wondering if there is a way to fire some code prior to user validation being actioned? I have code running in a plugin that fire `onBeforeSave` but validation is actioned before this. So was wondering if there is a function that can be run `onBeforeValidation` specifically for users.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Craft doesn't have any events related to validation.  You can see the full list of events available [here](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/events-reference).

You can always add it as a [feature request](http://feedback.buildwithcraft.com), though. Be sure and add examples of your specific use-case.